# Setting AD "pwdLastSet" to a large value using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm converting an old VB app to C# and being new to AD, I'm struggling with this bit of code which seems to set the 'pwdLastSet' property to a very high value (so that the user never has to change their password as far as I can tell)

```
'User must NOT change password at next logon
objLargeInt = CreateObject("LargeInteger")
objLargeInt.LowPart = &HFFFFFFFF
objLargeInt.HighPart = &HFFFFFFFF
Call objUser.Put("pwdLastSet", objLargeInt)
```

I've tried various methods in C# such as

```
user.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = Int64.MaxValue;
```

but nothing I do works (with various error messages). I can't find much in the docs either. I think I might need to use a "LargeInteger" type, and I've added a reference to a COM Library called "Active DS Type Library" but no idea if that's heading in the right direction or how to get any further really.

If someone can give me a clue what to do, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vb/s/a `&HFFFFFFFF == -1` as there is no unsigned support ... either way using that DS Type reference you can;

```
 var fatty = new ActiveDs.LargeInteger { HighPart = -1, LowPart = -1 };
```

Comment: Aha, that works perfectly, I had no idea that was the syntax I was aiming for. Thanks a million, really appreciate your help.